# NoSuchElementException: No line found (using hasNextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For the first time in mye relatively short programming life, I've run into a `NoSuchElementException`. I've done a bit of research, and none of the posts I've found trace back to a similar case. In many cases, the coder had simply [not put in hasNextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found), thus causing the Exception. Another example is when the coder tried to [read two lines consequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271775/using-hasnextline-but-still-getting-java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line/23271807#23271807), which also caused the error. A third tried got a solution with a [check for an empty line at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161051/keep-getting-nosuchelementexception-using-scanner), and this I feel might lie closer to my problem. However, I do not feel this is the solution I'm looking for. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Scanner; import java.io.*;

class DVDAdministrasjon
{
  private String eier;
  private String laaner;
  private boolean utlaant;
  private String tittel;

  private HashMap<String, DVD> dvdListe = new HashMap<String, DVD>();
  private HashMap<String, Person> personListe = new HashMap<String, Person>();

  public void lesDVDarkiv(String filnavn) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
    String curDVD = "";
    String inData; //lagrer data fra filen

    while (fil.hasNextLine())
    {
      inData = fil.nextLine();
      while (inData.equals("")) //Hopper over eventuelle linjeskift
      {
        inData = fil.nextLine();
      }
      if (inData.equals("-"))
      {
        inData = fil.nextLine();
        personListe.put(inData, new Person(inData));
      }
      else
      {
        inData = fil.nextLine();
        curDVD = inData;
        dvdListe.put(inData, new DVD(inData));
        if (curDVD.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("*"))
        {
          utlaant = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the **main** class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; import java.io.File;

class Oblig7Test1
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    DVDAdministrasjon dListe = new DVDAdministrasjon();
    dListe.lesDVDarkiv("dvdarkiv2.txt");
  }
}
```

Do keep in mind this program will be extended far beyond what is now visible. It is also for an assignment, but I am only interested in why I'm getting the error. The file consists of lines with more than one word in some lines, with "*" at the beginning of some lines and "-" as a divider between some lines.

The error looks like this:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at DVDAdministrasjon.lesDVDarkiv(DVDAdministrasjon.java:29)
    at Oblig7Test1.main(Oblig7Test1.java:9)
```

Comment: If you read javadoc of getNextLine()  you can see , "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped".  So how can you access multiple lines checking for one hasNextLine() ?

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson `getNextLine()` - where does this come from?

Comment: You need to check `hasNextLine()` every time before you call `nextLine()`.  You've just read to the end of the file

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry nextLine(), was a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code I have added some comments

```
while (fil.hasNextLine())  // if it enters here it has more lines
{
  inData = fil.nextLine();  // OK can read as hasNextLine returned true
  while (inData.equals("")) 
  {
    inData = fil.nextLine();  // NO guarantee that there is a `nextLine`
```

Without understanding you code fully I would suggest that if you need to read the next line then you should either `contune` to the top of your loop or test again using `if (fil.hasNextLine())`

Comment: I did not think of that, but it solved my problem. I understand the reasoning :-) I have definitely learnt something, and will bear this in mind while learning more!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In your second while loop do the following:

```
while (inData.equals("") && **fil.hasNextLine()**) //this second conditions ensure that it will enter while only if it has next line to read, else it passes to the next if condition
      {
        inData = fil.nextLine();
      }
```